# Iterating through children name swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

This is the current firebase structure:
[image]

The top part is the user's id, and I want to go into the createdEvents area, and print just eventTest and eventTest1, because those are their createdEvents. How would I do this?

```
 var ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id!).child("createdEvents")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount)
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
               print(rest.value)
            }
        }
```

This is what I have so far, but it keeps printing:

```
2
Optional({
    F5IRU4QrMvPToJnCA39lhjCGYh82 = F5IRU4QrMvPToJnCA39lhjCGYh82;
    Nge0cDX4lWVWfJROSypLFRLkCPI2 = Nge0cDX4lWVWfJROSypLFRLkCPI2;
})
Optional({
    F5IRU4QrMvPToJnCA39lhjCGYh82 = F5IRU4QrMvPToJnCA39lhjCGYh82;
})
```

which is just the things inside eventTest and eventTest1. How do I fix this?

Comment: What's the issue here? You're reading the createdEvent node by .value and then iterating over the child nodes which are eventTest and eventTest1 and printing their child nodes. It's working as intended - what else do you want? The names of the nodes? That would be snapshot.key for each child node.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, thanks to Jay, all I had to do was print rest.key not rest.value. Very simple solution, sorry about that.